# How to add multiple filter conditions based on incoming parameters to the Exposed DAO API ".find"

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-exposed

I am writing a dropwizard application using kotlin and one of the resource methods will receives multiple parameters(email, phone, is_deleted, etc). Based on the incoming query params, I have to filter the table. I am using DAO API of Exposed to construct the query.

`val result = User.find { //SqlExpressionBuilder
    Users.isDeleted eq false
    Users.email eq "so@soso.com"
}.sortedByDescending { it.createdAt }`

How to add multiple where conditions to the query based on the map of query params using a for in loop?

Comment: Do you mean "map of query params" is state of `isDeleted` and `email` in your example? And how much such maps you expect to have in the loop? 
It's not very effective to combine a very complex query condition, because your database can't use indices, sometimes it's better to make 10 simple and fast queries instead.

Comment: Yes. Those are table fields which are searchable via query params. The given snippet is just an example. The search query params are indexed columns in the table. At max 6 params is what I am expecting. But it could be any combination like email, is_deleted, email and is_deleted, email and is_deleted and phone, email and phone, etc. It could be any combination. So I need to frame the where condition according to the presence of the params.

Comment: You can try to check ["conditional where"](https://github.com/JetBrains/Exposed/wiki/DSL#conditional-where) wiki section. And write your own `orWhere` function similar to `andWhere`

Comment: @Tapac, thanks and I know that with DSL I can make it work. I just want to know, using DAO can we do it.

Comment: Then the only option is to use: `User.wrapRows(query).sortedByDescending()` and setup `query` within loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to solve the problem using DSL. Seems like DAO doesn't have such provision to create such adhoc query.

```
val query = Users.selectAll()
for((k, v) in params) {
    val value = URLDecoder.decode(v, "UTF-8")
    when(value) {
        "email" -> query.andWhere { Users.email eq value }
        "phone" -> query.andWhere { Users.phone eq value }
    }
}
return query.andWhere { Users.isDeleted.eq(false) }
```

As @Tapac mentioned, one can use `User.wrapRows(query).sortedByDescending()` also to frame such query but again one have to use DSL.

Hope that helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible:

```
val email = URLDecoder.decode("email", "UTF-8")
val phone = URLDecoder.decode("phone", "UTF-8")

Users.find {
  if (email != null) (Users.email eq email) else Op.TRUE
  .and(if (phone != null) (Users.phone eq phone) else Op.TRUE)
}
```